# Excel Display rank largest to smallest in another column formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, epplus

So I have a column that calculates the average. I want to get the values of that column and rank it largest to smallest  in another cell. The rank is from 1 to N. This is the desired output:
[image: Excel desired output]

As you can see, the values of avg column are ranked in rank column from largest to smallest. How to do this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the RANK formula :)

```
=RANK(B2, B$2:B$15, 0)
```